# ArgumentCountError in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to add social authentication to a Laravel 5.8 API project using socialite.

When trying to handle a social provide callback, the `ArgumentCountError` is thrown here

> Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\SocialAuthController::handleProviderCallback(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected

The error is referring to the very first line of this code block

```
public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
{
    // retrieve social user info
    $socialUser = Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->user();

    // check if social user provider record is stored
    $userSocialAccount = SocialAccount::where('provider_id', $socialUser->id)->where('provider_name', $provider)->first();

    if ($userSocialAccount) {

        // retrieve the user from users store
        $user = User::find($userSocialAccount->user_id);

        // assign access token to user
        $token = $user->createToken('Pramopro')->accessToken;

        // return access token & user data
        return response()->json([
            'token' => $token,
            'user'  => (new UserResource($user))
        ]);
    } else {

        // store the new user record
        $user = User::create([
            'name'                  => $socialUser->name,
            'username'             => $socialUser->email,
            'email_verified_at'    => now()
        ]);

        ...

        // assign passport token to user
        $token = $user->createToken('******')->accessToken;


        // return response
        return response()->json(['token' => $token]);
    }
}
```

Below is how I have set up other code. Frist in `env` I added

```
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=******
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET=*******
GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URL=https://staging.appdomain.com/api/v1/user
```

Then modified `web.php`

```
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);

Route::get('/auth/{provider}', 'SocialAuthController@redirectToProvider');

Route::get('/auth/{provider}/callback', 'SocialAuthController@handleProviderCallback');
```

Lastly in the google app, I added the uri path where users will be redirected to after successful authentication

```
https://staging.appdomain.com/api/v1/user
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Which is the url address when you get the error?

Comment: @mdexp the url is `https://staging.appdomain.com/api/v1/user?state=.....`

Comment: you're missing parameter there, you need to send $provider parameter when you firing the function

Answer (score 0):

The callback uri that user should be redirected to after successful authentication was apparently not being cached. So running `php artisan route:cache` fixed it.